# ¿Puede un punto y coma estar entre dos signos de admiración?

Tags: puntuación

La respuesta parece ser positiva, pero me pregunto si hay una regla que lo justifique (o prohiba).

Me refiero a oraciones del tipo:

> ¡primera parte; segunda parte!

No sé si eso expresa la idea que quiero:

> ¡primera parte!; ¡segunda parte! (probablemente erróneo)

Ésta, sin embargo, no es correcta, dado que después de los signos de admiración no pueden aparecer puntos, y no sé si punto y coma sea correcto.

Comment: — ¿Por qué piensas que después de un signo de admiración no es posible otra puntuación? — dijo alguien. (Y lo mismo, con comillas en vez de rayas)

Comment: A mi me  parecen muy raros esos ejemplos, nunca los he leído

Comment: No dispongo de ninguna referencia para apoyar mi opinión, pero entiendo que el punto y coma establece una pausa más larga que la coma, y rompe la entonación de una exclamación, convirtiéndola en dos exclamaciones separadas o en una exclamación y una afirmación.

Comment: @BlasSoriano Eso es lo que opino yo también. Si una persona hace una pausa en una exclamación, ¡son dos exclamaciones!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo recordar de mis años de bachillerato que el punto y coma se usaba para separar elementos de enumeración o frases sintácticamente independientes pero que están relacionadas semánticamente.

> Diego es de España; Alejandro de Chile
>
> Diego estudia informática en la Politécnica; Juan derecho en la Autónoma.

Dado que ese punto y coma escrito es una pausa que puede ser indistinguible al hablar de una coma o un punto y seguido es fácil preguntarse si se puede o debe mantener el énfasis de la exclamación teniendo esa pausa ahí, pero no hay ninguna razón por la que no puedas hacerlo:

> Cada puerta se pintará de un color: la primera, roja; la segunda, verde; la tercera, amarilla

Puede ser exclamado (cual orden en el ejército) como

> ¡Cada puerta se pintará de un color: la primera, roja; la segunda, verde; la tercera, amarilla!

Comment: Creí que había dado en el clavo con mi respuesta, pero tu ejemplo es indudable. Se pierde el sentido de la oración si encierras cada puerta en exclamaciones separadas.

Comment: La respuesta es correcta. No obstante, si yo escribiese esa frase lo haría así: `¡Cada puerta se pintará de un color! La primera, roja; la segunda, verde; la tercera, amarilla.` Me resulta más sencillo imaginar la entonación de este modo.

Answer (score 2):

Desconozco las reglas al respecto, pero me parece que debes considerar que los signos de exclamación son esencialmente **prosódicos**, y por lo tanto cabe preguntarse si es posible mantener la entonación enfática entre pausas largas.

Entonces creo que es semánticamente correcto englobar en un solo grupo de énfasis varias "secciones", como en tu ejemplo

> ¡primera parte; segunda parte!

pero me parece "poco pronunciable".

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Nunca lo he visto en ninguna parte.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más común sería separar los enunciados:

> ¡Primera parte!
>   ¡Segunda parte!

Porque normalmente se termina una idea y comienza la otra, es decir, primera parte en exclamación es poco común que se exclame junto con segunda parte.

Comment: Posiblemente, pero por esa regla de tres, con exclamación o sin ella, no tendrías motivos para usar el punto y coma, que es el quid de esta cuestión.